# Java app can't connect to local postgresql

Tags: java, macos, postgresql, jdbc

I have a simple Java application that needs to connect to a PostgresSQL running on local host. The DB is up and running, and I can connect to it using the username and password using the psql command line utility.
Here's the code:

```
try {
   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(DbLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

try ( 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db",
                    "user",
                    "pass");
 ){
// PROBLEM: con is null at this point
 } catch ( SQLException sqex ) {
    sqex.printStackTrace( System.out );
 }
```

Using Mac OS X.8.3.
There is no exception thrown.

Here is the output of pg_config:

```
BINDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
DOCDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/doc
HTMLDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/doc
INCLUDEDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include/server
LIBDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib
LOCALEDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/locale
MANDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/man
SHAREDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share
SYSCONFDIR = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/etc
PGXS = /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--prefix=/Users/mattt/Code/heroku/PostgresApp/Postgres/Vendor/postgres' '--enable-thread-safety' '--without-docdir' '--with-openssl' '--with-gssapi' '--with-bonjour' '--with-krb5' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--with-perl' '--with-python'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libxml2 
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif- labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
CFLAGS_SL = 
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
LDFLAGS_EX = 
LDFLAGS_SL = 
LIBS = -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lreadline -lm 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.1.4
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the stacktrace in order to get real help.

Comment: Are you catching exceptions? You should: `try { ... } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: By the way, don't you need a port to connect to your database? Looks like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db` needs it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: you don't need a port. If nothing is specified the driver will use the default port. But the question is impossible to answer without the actual error message.

Comment: @MichaelBarSinai: check out these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgres+osx+connection+problem

Answer (score 1):

Got it - programmer (that's me!) error.
I was passing the connection to another class, and that class had a null check that was not looking at the correct variables.

Takeaway - suspect yourself before you suspect PostgreSQL.

Thanks for all the comments!
-- M